# Algorithm for comparing two signals

Tags: algorithm, signals

Say we have streaming data coming from two input wires, Wire A and Wire B. The inputs are increasing integers.

For example,

A : 0, 5, 8, 15, 19, ...

B : 0, 4, 9, 14, 20, ...

So what we want to check is whether that data from the two inputs is consistent within some degree of variation, say some threshold on difference. 
My intuition for consistency right now is all big changes seen from one source should be available in the other, but it is open to discussion.
Also one condition is that it is not necessary that the two wires send equal number of inputs. Basically we can imagine the input as a sampling of continuous increasing signal, with no constraint that sampling is periodic.

Comment: Calculate average difference `sum(abs(a[i]-b[i]))/N`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very broad.

One fairly common thing you can do is check the Covariance. Since your inputs are always increasing I would first transform the streams into deltas (a[i]= a[i] - a[i-1] or something like that). Then compute the covariance (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)).

Assuming the deltas are random in nature, this will tell you how much they relate to each other. A value of 0 would mean that they are no consistent.
1 would be perfectly consistent and -1 would be perfectly inconsistent (when a is big then b is small and the other way around).

This is just something generic that you can try and play with. You have to look at the data and try different methods before you find something that works exactly the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the variation between the input in the series A and the serie B separately.
Ex:

```
A : 0, 5, 8, 15, 19, 
v(5 - 0) = 5
v(8 - 5) = 3
v(15 - 8) = 7
Vavg = (5+3+7)/3 = 5 (in this example)

B : 0, 4, 9, 14, 20
v(4-0) = 4
v(9 - 4) = 5
v(14 - 9) = 5
Vavg = (4+5+5)/3 = 4,6
```

so the variation between the series is, in this example, similar.
In this way you cannot check if the values in A are too bigger than B values.